# Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter, I am displaying all the job vacancies on one page, each individual job post has a button to view more information about the current post. when I try to pass the id variable for the individual post into the query I keep getting the error below.

Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'

query code

```
function get_vacancie($id) {

$query = $this->db->query('SELECT vacancies_id,name, vacancie_desc, pay FROM vacancies where vacancies_id=$id');
return $query = $query->row();


}
```

Comment: Single quoted string does not evaluate `$id` but uses it as-is. Change to double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT vacancies_id,name, vacancie_desc, pay FROM vacancies WHERE vacancies_id=' . $id);
```

This should work!

Answer (score 3):

Strings in single quotes doesn't evalute PHP variables. Change single-quotes to double-quotes and it will do the job:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancies_id,name, vacancie_desc, pay FROM vacancies where vacancies_id=$id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was single quote

```
function get_vacancie($id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancies_id,name, vacancie_desc, pay FROM vacancies where vacancies_id=$id");
return $query = $query->row();
}
```

Try this code with double code

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT vacancies_id,name, vacancie_desc, pay FROM vacancies WHERE vacancies_id={$id}");
```